# Difference between `exports` & `exports.x` in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have noticed a following snippet in `fs.js`

```
const fs = exports;
```

How does the the line given above differs from the following code which actually expose the object `x` outside the `exportSomething.js`.

```
exports.x = x
```

Particulary, I am unable to understand what `const fs = exports;` does.

Comment: `exports` is an object and `exports.x` is where `x` a property of `exports`.

Comment: There’s no magic in `exports`; it’s just an object. `const fs = exports;` names the same object `fs`.

Comment: [Note that the `exports` object comes from Node](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_the_module_wrapper) - it's not part of the JavaScript language itself.